# Showing $\ln\left(1+\frac{1}{x}\right)-\frac{1}{x+1}>0$ holds algebraically

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus

While solving a problem, I stuck at a very basic step. I need to show the following expression holds

$$\ln\left(1+\frac{1}{x}\right)-\frac{1}{x+1}>0$$ algebraically. I am open to any help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: use the fact that $ln(x) \leq x - 1$.

Comment: @BoraDoğan though the proof of that statement requires calculus, doesn't it? (I.e. can't purely be done "algebraically")

Comment: Since $\ln$ isn't an algebraic function, it's hard to imagine what an "algebraic" proof of this could be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note, the inequality makes no sense for $x\in[-1,0]$. So we can (indeed, must) assume that $0\not\in[x,x+1]$. For any such interval, we have

$$t\in(x,x+1)\implies{1\over t}\gt{1\over x+1}$$

Using the definition of the natural logarithm as an integral, we see that

$$\ln\left(1+{1\over x}\right)=\ln(x+1)-\ln x=\int_x^{x+1}{dt\over t}\gt\int_x^{x+1}{dt\over x+1}={(x+1)-x\over x+1}={1\over x+1}$$

Answer (score 2):

I assume $x>0$ for the sake of definiteness.
\begin{align}
\ln\left(1+\frac{1}{x}\right)-\frac{1}{x+1}>0& \iff(x+1)\ln\left(1+\frac{1}{x}\right)>1\\
&\iff\ln\left(\left(1+\frac{1}{x}\right)^{(x+1)}\right)>1\\
&\iff\left(1+\frac{1}{x}\right)^{(x+1)}>e.
\end{align}

It is an easy exercise to prove that the last inequality is satisfied $\forall x>0$.

Hint: the sequence $a_n=\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^{n+1}$ is decreasing and it converges to $e$.

Answer (score 2):

Consider $f(x) = \ln |x|$ and $f'(x) = 1/x$, for $x > 0$ or $x<-1$.

By mean value theorem, there exists a $c \in (x,x+1)$ that satisfy

$$f'(c) = \frac{f(x+1)-f(x)}{(x+1)-x} = \frac{\ln |x+1| - \ln |x|}{1} = \ln\left(1+\frac{1}{x}\right)$$

And $f'$ is decreasing, so

$$\begin{align*}
f'(c) &> f'(x+1)\\
\ln\left(1+\frac{1}{x}\right) &> \frac{1}{x+1}
\end{align*}$$

Answer (score 2):

**1. If we can use $e^x \ge x+1$:**

$$e^x \ge x+1.\tag{1}\label{eq1}$$

Make the substitution $x=-y$:

$$e^{-y}\ge 1-y \quad\Rightarrow\quad -y \ge \log(1-y).$$

Make the substitution $y=1/(z+1)$:

$$-1/(z+1) \ge \log\left(1-\frac{1}{z+1}\right)=\log\left(\frac{z}{z+1}\right).$$

Negate to get

$$\frac{1}{z+1}\le \log\frac{z+1}{z} = \log(1+1/z). \tag{2}\label{eq2}$$

We need to choose a range for $z$ so the final equation avoids division by zero or logs of nonpositive values. Let's use $z>0$. This means $y\in(0,1)$ and $z\in(-1,0)$. In that range, $\eqref{eq1}$ is a strict inequality; thus $\eqref{eq2}$ becomes strict as well.

**2. If we can use an integral.**

When $f(t)$ is a strictly decreasing function, then

$$\int_a^{a+b}f(t) dt > b\cdot f(a+b).$$

This is a fun property to verify visually with a picture.

So
$$\log(1+1/x) = \log\left(\frac{x+1}{x}\right) = \log(x+1)-\log(x) = \int_x^{x+1}dt/t > \frac{1}{x+1},$$
for $x>0$.

Answer (score 1):

If you can use derivatives,
you can use integrals.

For $x > 1$,
$\ln(x)
=\int_1^x \frac{dt}{t}
$
so

$\begin{array}\\
\ln\left(1+\frac{1}{x}\right)-\frac{1}{x+1}
&=\ln(x+1)-\ln(x)-\frac{1}{x+1}\\
&=\int_x^{x+1}\frac{dt}{t}-\frac{1}{x+1}\\
&=\int_x^{x+1}\frac{dt}{t}-\int_x^{x+1}\frac{dt}{x+1}\\
&=\int_x^{x+1}(\frac1{t}-\frac1{x+1})dt\\
&\gt 0
\qquad \text{since } \frac1{t} > \frac1{x+1}
\text{ for } x < t < x+1\\
\text{Similarly}\\
\ln\left(1+\frac{1}{x}\right)-\frac{1}{x}
&=\ln(x+1)-\ln(x)-\frac{1}{x}\\
&=\int_x^{x+1}\frac{dt}{t}-\frac{1}{x}\\
&=\int_x^{x+1}\frac{dt}{t}-\int_x^{x+1}\frac{dt}{x}\\
&=\int_x^{x+1}(\frac1{t}-\frac1{x})dt\\
&\lt 0
\qquad \text{since } \frac1{t} < \frac1{x}
\text{ for } x < t < x+1\\
\end{array}
$